# TypeScript -> AST -> TypeScript

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree, esprima

Is there a way to parse a TypeScript file to an AST, modify the AST, and parse it then back to TypeScript as the tools [Esprima](http://esprima.org/) + [Escodegen](https://github.com/estools/escodegen) are able to?

Important is that I do NOT want to compile/transpile the TypeScript code first into JavaScript.

Comment: Might https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API#traversing-the-ast-with-a-little-linter be what you're after?

Comment: @JoeClay The problem is that there is apparently no way to modify the AST of the .ts file with the public API. I think this is what is discussed also here in [#7580](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7580). Am I right?

Comment: Looks like it ): You might have to do some digging through the private API if you want to achieve this right now, by the looks of things.

Comment: In https://astexplorer.net/ you could see your AST (under menu 'acorn' choose 'typescript')

Answer (score 7):

Yes, with Typescript 2.x you can transform ast. Here is a good blog post about it http://blog.scottlogic.com/2017/05/02/typescript-compiler-api-revisited.html. In the official typescript wiki it is not well documented yet.