# escodegen.generate throws Error: Unknown node type: undefined

Tags: node.js, esprima, escodegen

The following is the code that I have written

```
`js
  var esprima = require('esprima');
  var escodegen = require('escodegen');
  var a = "var a = 2";
  var ast = esprima.tokenize(a);
  var output = escodegen.generate(ast);
  console.log(output);
`
```

I am able to tokenize the code string but I am getting error generating the code back. I went through multiple samples, Everywhere the same pattern is followed. I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `esprima.tokenize` does not generate an AST, just an array of tokens. What you want to use is `esprima.parse`.

Try this:

```
  var esprima = require('esprima');
  var escodegen = require('escodegen');
  var a = "var a = 2";
  var ast = esprima.parse(a);
  var output = escodegen.generate(ast);
  console.log(output);
```

It will work

Comment: Thanks but its working for a small code snippet. I am trying to parse a large code block of typescript for which it is throwing 'Unexpected token :' error.

Comment: Well, that is a different problem. I think esprima cannot parse typescript, maybe you can find some information in this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39917907/typescript-ast-typescript

Comment: Got it! Thanks for your help.